# Use spam assasin to block message with From and To address the same

Tags: email, spam, zimbra

I am using zimbra server as our email server. Today I saw some weird emails in my inbox. The **From** and **To** address both belongs to my email address. The header of the email.

```
To: toqeer@domain.com
From: "toqeer@domain.com
```

But Received address is the following.

```
Received: from p3smtphosting04-02.prod.phx3.secureserver.net (p3smtphosting04-02.prod.phx3.secureserver.net [208.109.80.81])
```

Is there any solution if **To** and **From** address is my own that should go to SPAM folder. I know **From** address could be anything and generally this could not be stopped but at-least it goes to Junk. If there is any general rule I can add to spamassasin, so if the **From** and **To** matches it should be considered as SPAM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do implement this, it will likely do more harm than good. A *lot* of people do this when Bcc'ing a large group of people. They put themselves in the To: field and Bcc: everyone else. You'll just end up up with a lot of false positives.

Just ensure that you've classified this and other emails like it as spam in SA and let the heuristics do their thing.